# How can I preset the geolocation on iPhone through xCode build settings?

Tags: iphone, xcode, geolocation

Here are some steps of what I am trying to accomplish:

> 1) In XCode, I am creating a new single view project.
>
> 2) Without the app doing anything, I am deploying it to my iPhone.
>
> 3) What I would like to do is specify a setting for the app so that when it gets built/installed on my iPhone through xCode, it will trick my iPhone into thinking I'm in a specific city.
>
> 4) When I open maps, it should default the current location to the city specified in #3.
>
> 5) Once my phone pings the carrier it will then pick up my current location and be accurate once again.

The problem I am running into is that I can not find the place to specify the default city location in #3.

Comment: Figured this out. TO accomplish, you need to go into file menu -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Core Location -> Default Location -> _SET TO WHEREVER YOU WOULD LIKE_

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

TO accomplish, you need to go into file menu -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Core Location -> Default Location -> SET TO WHEREVER YOU WOULD LIKE

Comment: This option is only available when running the app in DEBUG mode.